# recuperar datos especificos de realtime database con android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

tengo en android studio 1 campos de textos, 1 texview y un boton, base de datos en tiempo real tiene:

```
mybasededatos
   primerHijoDocumentos
      primerchild
           informacion:"prueba"
           fecha:"20 de julio"
           autor:"Axl"
      segundochild
           informacion:"prueba2"
           fecha:"21 de julio"
           autor:"Axl"
```

y lo que no entiendo como hacer es que, si escribo en los 2 Edit Text, la fecha y el autor, como hago que especificamente me imprima esa informacion, la idea es que, solo con tener 2 datos de un child, pueda guardar en un string otro child que quiera en especifico de ese mismo

tengo algo como

```
 mRootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("primerHijoDocumentos");

for (dataSnapshot user Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
         String fecha = userSnapshot.child("fecha");
         String autor = userSnapshot.child("autor");

            if(fecha.equals(TextoIngresado)){
                      /*aqui no se como solicitar que imprima en el textview la 
informacion de acuerdo a lo que encuentra con esos 2 campos que busca con el if, segun tengo 
entendido, ese user spanshot.child busca eso en todos, pero aun no me queda muy claro que digamos. */
            }
}
```

Comment: Para obtener los datos tienes que acceder a `primerchild` y `segundochild`. La pregunta no es clara, por ejemplo, ¿`primerchild` y `segundochild` son valores fijos o dinámicos? ¿siempre hay dos o puede haber más?

Comment: y si primerchild y segundochild los hago con push para que sus nombres sean caracteres? son valores fijos, y si puede haber mas, la idea es que pueda añadir muchos child con esos 3 de fecha autor e informacion y si busco fecha y autor me pueda dar la informacion

Comment: El problema entonces es que esa forma de organizar los datos luego no te permitirá acceder a ellos de manera dinámica. Para poder acceder a esto por ejemplo: `20 de julio` primero tendrás que hacer referencia al padre de ese nodo que es `primerchild`, pero si hay eventuales, `tercerchild`, `cuartochild`, `vigesimochild` no es para nada evidente acceder de forma dinámica a cada nodo. Firebasa, al ser No SQL te obliga a pensar en cómo necesitarás consultar los datos antes de diseñar la estructura de los mismos.